# How to get user profile details using Azure AD

Tags: reactjs, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am using react-aad-masl module to integrate Microsoft SSO in my react application. I am able to redirect my user to Microsoft login page and after that its coming back to my page with token. After that its only returning `accountInfo` that contain User name and email ID. I have a requirement to get user other details as well like ID, first name, last name, Group, etc.

These all details will come through this Azure AD MASL or i need to do Graph API call?

Below is my implementation

//authProvider.js

```
import { MsalAuthProvider, LoginType } from 'react-aad-msal';
import { Logger, LogLevel } from "msal";

// Msal Configurations
const config = {
  auth: {
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/*********',
    clientId: '*************',
    redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000/'
  },
  // Enable logging of MSAL events for easier troubleshooting.
  // This should be disabled in production builds.
  system: {
    logger: new Logger(
      (logLevel, message, containsPii) => {
        console.log("[MSAL]", message);
      },
      {
        level: LogLevel.Verbose,
        piiLoggingEnabled: false
      }
    )
  },
  cache: {
    cacheLocation: "sessionStorage",
    storeAuthStateInCookie: true
  }
};
 
// Authentication Parameters
const authenticationParameters = {
  scopes: [
    'user.read',
    'profile',
    'openid'
    //'profile.read', 
    // 'User.Read.All',
    // 'Group.Read.All',
    // 'User.ReadBasic.All',
    // 'Group.Read'
  ]
}
 
// Options
const options = {
  loginType: LoginType.Redirect,
  tokenRefreshUri: window.location.origin + '/auth.html'
}
 
export const authProvider = new MsalAuthProvider(config, authenticationParameters, options)
```

//APP.js

```
<AzureAD provider={authProvider}  forceLogin={false}>
      {(abc) => {
          console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>...', abc);
          
          props.setAccountInfo(abc.accountInfo.account);
          return <AppRouter />
      }}
      </AzureAD>
```

Here in abc i am getting below information

[image]

Please help me in this

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure the optional claims in the application token configuration for First Name, Last Name.

[image]

Please go through the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) for more information

Regarding the group information please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps)

Comment: Raghavendra - thanks for your response, in this claims is there a way to get User ID and Group as well? Because mainly i need these 2 attributes for user.  Also this information will be available under accountInfo property?

Comment: you can get the approles by making changes in the app manifest. Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#approles-attribute) and for security groups please refer [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest#approles-attribute) . In the Token 'oid' is the unique user id across the tenant and  if a single user exists in multiple tenants, the user will contain a different object ID in each tenant

Comment: Raghavendra - If i update manifest file then i will be able to get approles in accountInfo itself form Azure AD or i will need to do separate graph API call

Comment: with the manifest changes for app roles you will be able to get the roles information in the token. No need of graph api call